# Refering in one layer to another layer in ModelBuilder or ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, advanced-license-level, if-else

I have a problem in using Python in ModelBuilder.

My model is going to calculate pace of lateral erosion.

I subtracted two polygon layers by [Symmetrical Difference](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/symmetrical-difference.htm) and add field "tempo" to new layer with expression in "Wyrażenie na tempo" "Shape Area"/55.5 (55.5 is length of my segment). There is no problem when pace is positive because Symmetrical Difference's output is an absolute value. The problem is when pace should be below zero.

I should use some kind of if statement but I don't know how.

My statement should be like this:

```
If Shape Area of Dane 2 > Shape Area of Dane1: tempo * (-1)
else: tempo *1
```

I'm not sure where in model should I use it (maybe add next Calculate Field Tool or write a script) and how to refer in one layer to other layers.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  You have mentioned arcpy in your tags and title, but I'm unsure how arcpy relates to your question.  Can you please [edit] and clarify?

Comment: You could do this all in python, but I think using the Get Field Value tool in the Model Only Tools in model builder you could do this. Then use calculate tool to do your equation.

Answer (score 1):

You say that:

> Symmetrical Difference's output is an absolute value

but it is not.  Symmetrical Difference's output is a feature class.

Consequently, `tempo` is a feature class and multiplying it by any number makes no sense.  I'm assuming that you mean to add a field called `tempo` to your feature class called `tempo` and then multiply that by 1 or -1.

As commented by @j.stanfield:

> I think using the Get Field Value tool in the Model Only Tools in
>   [ModelBuilder] you could do this. Then use [Calculate Field] tool to do your
>   equation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i undestand you correctly. It would be helpful if you just past your code, but as far as i am concert after your "Add field" can you just separate values which are below zero and values which are more than zero. After using "Select" or "Select by Attributes" just "Copy selected feature" and do what you want on new feature layer. And after edition just merge them back.

Tip
You can use Invert selection which is inside "Select by attributes" to get all values which are higher than 0.